# Trigger Google Assistant programmatically to make it read aloud a given String

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I was wondering whether I can pass a String to the Google Assistant from my App to let it be read aloud/spoken.
I have found these related posts, but the key questions haven't been answered yet:

- [How to start Google Assistant programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709191/how-to-start-google-assistant-programmatically)
- [How to send a text query to Google Assistant from Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822530/how-to-send-a-text-query-to-google-assistant-from-android-app)

Could you please point me into the right direction? An example would be nice.
I expect something like starting an activity to make Google Assistant read the given String.

Best regards
JJ

Comment: So you're looking for a way to generally use the Google Assistant voice for speech synthesis?

Comment: @Nick Yeah, that's correct! A good way to put it in a nutshell :D

Comment: Did you try finding the answer? I was looking for an assistant.
I'm trying to make google assistant listen to my instruction programmatically when I receive the incoming call. From the above link, I am able to open google assistant but not able to listen for my instruction.  I need to press microphone icon to listen. If you know the answer let me know. Thanks